# black screen on ubuntu startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wubi

I installed **Ubuntu** version *12.10* using **Wubi** on my lenovo laptop. When I choose to boot as Ubuntu, a black screen appeared and Ubuntu isn't starting. A few days earlier, I installed it on my hp laptop but this problem didn't appear. 
What's wrong?

Comment: Is anybody who can help me plz?

Comment: You choose wrong cite for you problem. Stack Overflow is for **programming** questions.

Comment: you mean that I should choose super user? @Tsyvarev

Comment: Yes, it Super User would be better choice.

Comment: Thanks man. @Tsyvarev

Comment: @Tsyvarev how can I put this question out of the`on hold` thing especially I knew that this question doesn't belong to Stack overflow after I wrote it. They had warned me that I should write more helpful question and in a matter way to continue in this site, so I should begin to repair these questions and I want help from you in this one. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, I don't know how one can improve definitely off-topic question. Probably, you need to concentrate on your other "bad" questions. However, I don't see them in you profile, are they are deleted (because my rep is lower than 10k, I cannot see deleted questions)? If this question is the only way for you to proceed, I would suggest to ask on [meta].

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes, I deleted some questions for several problems, thank you anyway bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ubuntu version 12.10

Ubuntu 12.10 is [EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_%28product%29). Better use 12.04, 14.04 or 15.10

> using Wubi

Official Wubi versions are not maintained. So there are some unfixed bugs and missing features. I use a community supported version from [here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases).

> a black screen appeared

It depends on your hardware. IMHO black screens need some boot options in GRUB menu. If you use Wubi, press SHIFT immediately after selecting Ubuntu.
In GRUB menu you can press 'e', then insert your boot options. e.g. if you want use **nomodeset** instead of **quiet splash**, change the line beginning with **linux** from

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-x.y-0-z-generic root=UUID=01234567890ABCDEDEF loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro rootflags=sync quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

to

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-x.y-0-z-generic root=UUID=01234567890ABCDEDEF loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro rootflags=sync nomodeset $vt_handoff
```

After changing this line, press F10 to boot.

During installation if you see:

```
Completing the Ubuntu installation.
For more installation boot options, press 'ESC' now...
```

you can press 'ESC' to get a GRUB menu.

Comment: I didn't get it. Plz clarify it more. @ngng

Comment: Did you get no GRUB menu ? Or did you get the GRUB menu and you cannot change boot options ? GRUB menu should appear after step 9 from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) if you press SHIFT immediately after selecting Ubuntu. But I don't know the right boot option because you didn't write detailed information about your laptop. There are a lot of different Lenovo models. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 using Wubi on a Lenovo laptop without any problems.

Comment: @Jonny Nassar: IMHO [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) is the right site for your question but your question will be closed if you use an unsupported Ubuntu version like 12.10. If it is a new Lenovo laptop you need support for new hardware. This means a new  supported Ubuntu version like [14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04) or [15.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/wily).